# How auto call a button submit ,when page is loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to call a button submit when page is loading.
I code as:

```
 (function($) {
              //Id of form: searchform
              document.searchform.submit(); 


    })(jQuery);
```

But Page request auto multy time. I want only auto submit one time when load page.
Can you help me? thanks.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I have this implemented in multiple scripts. Especially, if I need to prepare some parameters and then send them to a remote server via post method.

Comment: I have another system that I would like to login and automatically submit the form with the parameters I sent to it. The thing is, I have no access to this system code.
My challenge is to integrate two systems without changing one of the systems code.
In this case, I need to send the search parameters and submit the search so the user will see the results only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to submit it only once to the same page, you should add some kind of variable, that you check like this:

```
<form name="searchform" id="searchform" action="newpage.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="whatever" value="myvalue" />
  <input type="text" name="search" value="" />
  <?php if ( $_POST['whatever'] != 'myvalue' ) { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.searchform.submit();
  </script>
  <?php } ?>
</form>
```

This will submit only once, since the 2nd time there will be a post value.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that directly you can **submit** the form

**Example**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#form_id').submit();

});
```

**EDIT**

To avoid second time page submitting take one `hidden` field and check the value before call `submit()`

In view

```
<input type="hidden" id="visits" value="<?= $visit?>" />
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('#visits').val() == 1)
        $('#form_id').submit();

});
```

When you loading the page 1st time pass the value to `$visit` is `1`, any value other than `1`

Comment: This will **always** submit the form on each page load. Not what OP requested I guess.